# Этот человек у двери - preposition

Tags: предлоги

I heard the following sentence in a Russian learning tool:

> этот человек у двери.

Can this sentence be translated to English as both "this person is by the door" (= close to the door) and "this person is at the door" (= in front of the door, waiting after have rung the bell or called someone") ? Can "y" be replaced with "возле" here?

Comment: Is this a full sentence? (It should be capitalised, then).

Comment: Since there's no verb there, it can also be translated not as a sentence, but as a nominal phrase, "this man at/close to the door."

Comment: Yes, all these translations are possible + the nominal one. Yes, "у" can be replaced by "возле". The meaning is not affected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both translations of the sentence are correct. Preposition **y** is probably the best choice to express that someone is by the door, or in an interaction with it. (e.g. somebody waiting for someone at the door)

With preposition **возле**, the sentence would rather be translated to **"this person is close to the door"**, (e.g. someone lurking somewhere outside, near the door). It could be used if the location is important in the context.

**За дверью** could also be used if wanted to emphasize that someone is behind the door (closed or shut), e.g. hiding behind an opened door.